# How to pass Swift Bool value to Objective-C's method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, boolean

I have a `Mysevers` Class for network written by `Objective-c`, and now I use mixed `Objective-c` and `Swift` project.

In my `Mysevers`, I have a method to network:

```
+(void)AFPOSTWithHud:(BOOL)hud andAddressname:(NSString*)addressName parmas:(NSDictionary*)parmas RequestSuccess:(void(^)(id result))success failBlcok:(void(^)(void))failBlcok
{
    if (hud) {
        [HUD addHUD];
    }
    AFHTTPSessionManager *requestManager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",BASE_URL,addressName];
    NSLog(@"%@",urlStr);


    [requestManager POST:urlStr parameters:parmas progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {

    } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {

        if (hud) {
            [HUD removeHUD];
        }
        success(responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"error==%@",[error localizedDescription]);
        if (hud) {
            [HUD removeHUD];
            }

        }
        failBlcok();
    }];


}
```

In the `Swift` controller, invoke the method, pass a swift Bool value `false`.

```
 Mysevers.afpost(withHud: false, andAddressname: Global.url_fillMoreInfo, parmas: uploadDict, requestSuccess:{ (result) in
```

But, in the Mysevers class, I give a breakpoint to check the passed value, it turn out to be `YES`:

```
(lldb) po hud
YES
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. Perhaps you can create [a small, reproducible example of the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (specifically outlining what steps we need to take to experience the behavior you describe, starting from a blank project).